# Swift method parameter, any string in set

Tags: swift

I'm wondering if it's possible in Swift to specify that a parameter for a method must be one of several predetermined strings?

For example:

```
foo(meal: MealType) { ... }
```

In this example `meal` should be one of three strings:

```
MealType {    
    breakfast = "b"
    lunch = "l"
    dinner = "d"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an enum

```
enum MealType: String {
    case breakfast = "b"
    ...
}
```

Then, in your `foo(meal: MealType) { ... }`, check for the `meal.rawValue` to get the `String` value

If you want to make it more readable you can extend the enum like below

```
extension MealType {
    var identifier: String { return rawValue }
}
```

And then use `meal.identifier` instead of `rawValue`

Comment: haha I did try enum before but forgot to add string as the raw type! God I feel stupid, cheers! :)